# DAX Formula to check values in two columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two calculated columns in the same table which have values named "Transfer, blank() or Not Eligible. I want to identify accounts that do not have Transfers.

which DAX formula should I use?

the table looks like this, what is the formula if I need to get a result (TRUE/FALSE)

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Column = if(Table[Q1] = "Transfer" || Table[Q2] = "Transfer", TRUE(), FALSE())`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using calculated column

```
Column = if(Table[Q1] = "Transfer" || Table[Q2] = "Transfer", TRUE(), FALSE())
```

Comment: your formula have one mistake in ')'

Comment: `Column = if(Table[Q1] = "Transfer" || Table[Q2] = "Transfer", TRUE(), FALSE())`